# Make section that always is "on top"

Tags: css, html, properties, always-on-top

Is there any way to make a `section` in html that would always be shown as "on top"? Kinda like a menu bar, just to give an idea of what would that mean, but applied to a whole section.
In my particular case, I have a html divided mainly in two sections: the upper with a list, and this should be scrollable, and the lower one with a couple of buttons, but this one should **always** be seen by the user, because he/she might want to click one of the buttons without scrolling down(perhaps quite a lot) to get to the buttons.

Comment: can you add some HTML and CSS?

Comment: Well, so far there are just the two sections made up, one with a list one with a button, and nothing really related to what I need.

Comment: check out @Mike-Brant answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `position: fixed` to fix an element relative to the browser window.  This would give you your desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

you can try :

```
 postion:fixed;
 display: block; 
 top: 0px;
```